# How can I implement this code in ocaml?

Tags: list, ocaml

```
let rec list_add l i =
    match l with
      [] -> [i]
    | h::t -> h::(list_add t i)
```

list add for adding each pair of integers from two lists

*(Type)* `list add : int list -> int list -> int list`

*(Description)* `list add [a; b; c; ...] [x; y; z; ...]` returns `[a + x; b + y; c + z; ...]`. If one list is longer than the other, the remaining list of elements is appended to the result.

*(Example)* `list add [1; 2] [3; 4; 5]` returns `[4; 6; 5]`.

Comment: You've transcribed an assignment, but we don't want to write your code for you. What happens when you run the code you give here? What seems to be wrong with it? One tiny observation is that it doesn't perform any arithmetic at all.

Comment: A very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099672/function-bigadd-addition-of-two-int-lists

Answer (score -1):

```
let rec add l1 l2 = match l1 with
    [] -> l2
    |h::t -> (*you can do the rest*)
;;
```

Comment: This is not a useful answer since this question shouldn't have any answer at all. ;-)